# Add element to change with existing onblur

Tags: jquery, onblur

I would like a separate DIV that's holding the input to also change in background color.  How would I add it to my existing code that works?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("input:[type=text]").focus(function () {
 jQuery(this).addClass("highLightInput");

});
jQuery("input:[type=text]").blur(function () {
jQuery(this).removeClass("highLightInput");
});
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input:[type=text]").focus(function () {
 $(this).addClass("highLightInput");
$(this).parent('div').addClass('highlight');

});
$("input:[type=text]").blur(function () {
$(this).removeClass("highLightInput");
$(this).parent('div').removeClass('highlight');
});
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: I tried it and only the input changes.  Here is my html: <div id="quote_input" class="qty" style="width: 95px"> <input class="textQ"  style="width: 74px"> </div>

Comment: @Erik Moin's code looks correct.  Do you have a a `highlight` class defined for your `<div id="quote_input">`?

Comment: Thanks Moin... Your help did it.  I found a typo..  Many thanks.

Comment: i just used a class called 'highlight' either change it to 'hightLightInput' which will make it the same background as the input or add a new rule to your CSS like so: 'div.highlight {background:lightgreen;}'

Comment: Just curious, Could I add a select drop down to be included?

Comment: you can. is it beside the input? outside? You'll need to use the right selector to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Stop messing around with JavaScript for something that can be solved with CSS. The only limitation is that it will not support IE6/7

```
textarea.yourClass {
    width: 100%; 
    background: white url('iamges/img.png') no-repeat 50% 50%; 
    color: grey;
}
textarea.yourClass:focus {
    color: #444; 
    background: none;
}
```

If you do need to support IE6/7, then use above JS methods